# How to convert universal character name to its actual value in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

In my app, I am having chinese string in `UITextField`. I am doing as following.

```
NSString *strName = realNameTextField.text;

NSLog(@"result string: %@", strName);
```

Expected o/p:

> chinese string.

Getting o/p

> \U8f93\U5165\U7528\U6237\U540d

How would I get the actual string which is in chinese from my `UITextField`?

Comment: You have it. Use it for whatever you want, just don't rely on `NSLog` to always output exactly what formatted content you're expecting

Comment: Exactly..but when I am sending it through dictionary it goes as \U8f93\U5165\U7528\U6237\U540d

Comment: What do you mean by "sending it through dictionary"?

Comment: Unless you present the characters in a view that can understand Chinese characters they will always be presented as UTF escape codes.  The data is fine, it's the presentation that is not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *strName = realNameTextField.text;

    const char *cString = [strName UTF8String];


    //char cString[] = strName;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result string: %@", string);
```